# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row; foreign key restraint fails

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried to reference some of the previously asked Error #1452 questions asked here but I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. In my movies table, I want to make actor_id an FK that references the PK in the actor table. However I keep coming up with #1452 error. Where am I going wrong?

[image: Movie Table]

[image: Actor Table]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you already have some data in your database that are breaking the FK constraint (ie referencing id that does not exist).

Comment: Would you recommend deleting all the data out and then try setting the FK?

Comment: If you don't need the data, then that is an option :)